# Donde é que veio a «bófia»?

Tags: etimologia

***Bófia*** é em Portugal um nome informal e algo depreciativo para a instituição policial ou um agente policial. O Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) diz que é um lusitanismo. [Este artigo](https://tudonumclick.com/noticias/angola/29393/angola-eu-nunca-pensei-que-um-bofia-teria-coragem-de-defender-tanta-ilegalidade-aberracao-e-falta-de-rigor) sugere que o termo também é usado em Angola. Na minha experiência, *bófia* é uma palavra relativamente recente.

Não consegui foi descobrir donde veio a palavra. Vários dicionários dizem apenas que é de origem obscura. A [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/b%C3%B3fia) sugere que possa vir de [*embófia* (Infopédia)](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/emb%C3%B3fia), que é uma palavra que eu jamais ouvira ou lera, mas que significa «soberba, vaidade, basófia»; «patranha, impostura»; e ainda «pessoa presumida».

Donde é que veio então a *bófia*. Quando e onde é que o termo começou a ser usado, ou quando é que aparece no registo escrito?

Comment: Tudo o que pude encontrar diz que a origem é obscura.  "Bófia é de origem obscura, sabendo-se apenas que é palavra que surgiu do mundo do crime, estando hoje generalizada nos meios urbanos e, sobretudo, entre os jovens, em Portugal."  ( Novo Dicionário de Calão, de Afonso Praça, Notícias Editorial, Lisboa)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mais uma vez, o @Jacinto mencionou [resultados de ocorrencias mais antigas de bófia em textos portugueses](https://www.google.pt/search?q=b%C3%B3fia&num=50&lr=lang_pt&biw=1242&bih=580&tbs=lr:lang_1pt,sbd:1&tbm=bks&ei=6LFNWPqqEYKbaP30h6gN&start=100&sa=N&dpr=1.1).

No livro "Tratado de semântica geral aplicada à língua portuguêsa do Brasil", datado de 1947 autoria de Franscisco da Silveira Bueno contém mesmo a definição de bófia

> Bófia: agente da polícia

Como dito nos comentários pelo @Jacinto, a palavra parece ter maior antiguidade no idioma espanhol. Fica a referencia da pergunta feita pelo @Jacinto [na comunidade espanhola](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/de-d%C3%B3nde-ha-venido-la-bofia/19037#19037). Vou só passar o excerto da primeira ocorrencia na resposta dada por [carlos-alejo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12637/carlos-alejo)

> Según el [CORDE](http://www.rae.es/recursos/banco-de-datos/corde), la
>   primera aparición de la palabra en un texto con el significado que
>   mencionas, es el siguiente: (Segundo el CORDE, a primeira ocorrência
>   da palavra num texto, com o significado que mencionas é o seguinte:)
>
> - ¿Y llevaba dinero encima?
> - Siempre. Dinero y alhajas; llevaba sobre su persona un capital. Pero no vayas a sospechar de mi novio. Es muy chulo, pero muy decente. No
>     sé por qué me figuro que tú eres de la bofia.
>
> Emilio Carrere, "La torre de los siete jorobados", circa 1923
>   (España).

Comment: Obrigado pela pesquisa. Mas há o [Jaime Bunda - Agente Secreto](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vS0v1DOeOd0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-PT#v=onepage&q&f=false), do mesmo autor(a?), com primeira edição de 2001. Na lista do Google fica logo abaixo do que tu clicaste. Interessante, que parece ser angolano.

Comment: @Jacinto Eu vi que ele tinha pelo menos 4 edicoes do livro. Parece que vendeu bem xD

Comment: @Jacinto Encontrei um referencia datada de 1996 parece que a minha pesquisa anterior que limitava ocorrencias desde 2000 nao foi a mais acertada :p

Comment: Bruno, não sei que raio de busca fizeste. [Olha nesta página](https://www.google.pt/search?q=b%C3%B3fia&num=50&lr=lang_pt&biw=1242&bih=580&tbs=lr:lang_1pt,sbd:1&tbm=bks&ei=6LFNWPqqEYKbaP30h6gN&start=100&sa=N&dpr=1.1): encontras livros de 1982 e 1983 e uma enciclopédia de 195? em Portugal, e publicações brasileiras de 1947 e 1948! Vê também [a pergunta que abri no Spanish SE](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/de-d%C3%B3nde-ha-venido-la-bofia/19037#19037). Encontraram um livro de 1923.

Comment: @Jacinto feito, acho que nao dei conta do link para a pergunta na comunidade espanhola.

Comment: Vê [esta página](https://www.google.pt/search?q=b%C3%B3fia&num=50&lr=lang_pt&biw=1242&bih=580&tbs=lr:lang_1pt,sbd:1&tbm=bks&ei=6LFNWPqqEYKbaP30h6gN&start=100&sa=N&dpr=1.1) de resultados em português: tens ocorrências a partir de 1948, acho.

Comment: @Jacinto e Bruno já está atualizada a resposta? Posso apagar os comentários?

Comment: @JorgeB. Para agora parece estar

Comment: Bruno e @JorgeB. eu não mencionei nenhum resultado de 1941; mencionei de 1947 e 1948. Não precisas de me dar crédito na resposta. Pá, esses têm *bófia*

Comment: @Jacinto Claro que dou, nao fui eu quem fez a pesquisa. Por uma razao qualquer os meus resultados da procura parecem ser diferentes dos teus.  Só se for por estar noutro país...

Answer (score 0):

Bófia é uma palavra extremamente detrimente usada como substituto de Polícia ou Guarda (referência à Guarda Nacional Republicana, força policial em pequenas povoações ou zonas rurais em Portugal).
Bófia tem origem em Bofe, nome usado para pulmões de animais ou carne de péssima qualidade que quando cozinhado tem odor desagradável e muito intenso.

Comment: Essa origem em *bofe* precisaria de ser fundamentada.

Answer (score -1):

Tudo treta! e ninguém assume o termo. Bófia vem do termo antigo calão de "bufar" termo usado na altura em que a PIDE Portuguesa tinha à sua disposição vários "Bufos" que ganhavam com a ajuda aos Polícias, os quais (Policias) tb ganhavam com a denúncia dos elementos contra o regime, embora não venha em dicionários, ou venha mal traduzido associando a elementos das Forças de Segurança, não mais é que um termo pejorativo para insultar quem trabalha como Polícia, e como a Polícia é o informante (do mal que acontece na Sociedade) do estado lá está o termo "Bufo" Queixinhas, Delator, etc. Daí nenhum Polícia que se prese gosta do termo. Só quem têm elementos na família ou falou com gerações antigas de Polícias conhece a origem da palavra que ninguém quer ou têm coragem de traduzir, Espero ter esclarecido cumprimentos a todos.
Ferreira Agente da P.S.P.

Comment: Bem vindo ao Portuguese SE. Tente manter seu texto mais formal e dividir frases com pontos, pois frases compridas sem pontos normalmente ficam enfadonhas para se ler e difíceis de se interpretar. Se possível, por se tratar de uma comunidade de estudo do idioma, também atenha-se às normas de uso de letras maiúsculas e minúsculas.